# How can I compute the sum of a vector with a condition?

Tags: calculus, algorithms

Let $SUM(X_i;0,...0;cond)$ be the sum of a vector $X$ from element $i = 0,…,n$ with a condition cond. If the condition is not fulfilled, the result is $0$.

Given $K_0=[1, 2, 3]$ and  $K_1=[7, 8, 9, 10]$ ;
Let $f=1$

For $j$=$f$ to $0$, how to find

$$X+SUM(K_i;j,...,f-1;j<f)$$

The reference at page 84 in [here](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_tr/102900_102999/102993/01.01.01_60/tr_102993v010101p.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your definition for $SUM(X_i; 0, \ldots, n; cond)$ states that if the condition is not met, then the sum is 0. Only if the condition is met, the value of $SUM(\ldots)$ will be equal to the sum of the specified elements of $X_i$.

Thus, for your example expression it holds that

\begin{align*}
  X + SUM(K_i; j, \ldots, f - 1; j < f) = \begin{cases}
    \sum_{k = j}^{f - 1} K_i[k], & \text{if } j < f \text{ and} \\
    0 & \text{else.}
  \end{cases}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank philipph, $K_i[k]$ means the size or data of $K_i$?

Comment: By $K_i[k]$ I refer to the $k$-th element of list $K_i$, so its the data. In other words, your expression is 0 if $j \eq f$ and the sum of all elements starting at the $j$-th element and ending at the $(f-1)$-th element otherwise.